# googlemock: mock a local object

Tags: c++, googlemock

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"  

class Turtle{
    public:
        int foo(); 
};

int func(){
    Turtle local_tutrtle;
    auto x = local_tutle.foo(); 

    ......

    return x;
}

TEST(mock, foo) {
    class MockTurtle : public Turtle {
        public:
            MOCK_METHOD0(foo, int());
    };

    ASSERT_EQ(10, func());
}
```

How can I mock the local_turtle in func()? I want to change the return value of local_tutle.foo() without modifying func();

Thanks.

Comment: Pass `local_turtle` as an argument. Or pass some sort of a Turtle Factory to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

You have to supplement mocked object (in your example turtle) from the outside, by passing (mocked or nomral) turtle object as an argument.

This design pattern is called dependency injection, and you should get familiar with it as soon as possible, because it's very important in designing easily testable applications and frequently used.